# How to install Printer drivers

Tags: installation, drivers

I have two questions:

1. Once downloaded install it directly without uninstalling window 7 right?
2. where do I download drivers for the printers?

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to include which printer model you have, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to uninstall anything from windows to use a printer from Ubuntu.

How to install a printer in Ubuntu can depend upon the printer brand and model. Ubuntu comes with support for many (almost all?) printers without having to download anything or install anything else.

Having said that, some printer manufacturers may make available special driver for Ubuntu/Debian systems.

After you have connected the printer to your system, or to your network, the place to start is to go to the Gear icon at the top right of your screen and choose "Printers". Then you can use the "+" button to add your printer. Details will vary depending on how the printer is connected to your computer and whether you want to share it, for example.

As Jorge suggested above it would be helpful for us to know more about your printer. You can click edit under your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your choice. Do you want to be able to use Windows 7, or do you not care about it? Either way, refer to https://askubuntu.com/a/152902/54298. If you choose to keep Windows, you will be able to choose every time you turn your computer on, and they will act independently of each other. If you remove Windows, you can install it again later if you have a disk for it.
2. Please provide your printer type and I will give you a driver link here by editing this post.

---

1. La vostra scelta. Vuoi essere in grado di utilizzare Windows 7, o non ti interessa questo? In entrambi i casi, fare riferimento a https://askubuntu.com/a/152902/54298. Se si sceglie di mantenere Windows, sarete in grado di scegliere ogni volta che si accende il computer, ed essi agiscono in modo indipendente l'uno dall'altro. Se si rimuove Windows, è possibile installare un secondo momento se si dispone di un disco per esso.
2. Si prega di fornire il tipo di stampante e io vi darò un link driver qui modificando questo post.